# Twitter pull up functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, uiview

I am looking for some direction towards sample code or a library already out there, but I would like to try and implement the functionality that twitter has when viewing a picture with having a subview that you can pull up from the bottom and reveal the caption along with some options.  I can design that subview but I cannot figure out how they get it to show ontop and then allow you to pull it up.  Any direction is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Basically I want to present a sub view like a modal

Answer (score 0):

something like this [cocoa control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pullableview) should get you going in the right direction.